Is there a function that can return the median value of an image expression
There is a function to get the median from number expressions in DM. For example:
// number expression
number x=3, y=5, z=10;
number num = median(x, pi(), y,z);
OKDialog( "num = " + num);

However, this function does not work for image expression :
// image expression
image img := exprsize(5, icol);
number num = img.median();
OKDialog( "num = " + num );

Any solution? Thanks.

I believe you're looking for ImageGetMedian() as per the F1 help documentation:


ImageGetMedian() is available since GMS 3.4 (didn't check earlier versions). Documented in GMS 3.6.

You were undoubtedly hoping for a faster and more elegant solution, but I think the following works:
// Get front image and some info about it
Image sourceImg := GetFrontImage();
Number srcW = sourceImg.ImageGetDimensionSize(0);
Number srcH = sourceImg.ImageGetDimensionSize(1);
Number srcMax = sourceImg.Max();
Number srcMin = sourceImg.Min();

// Form histogram of its values with binCount channels
Number binCount = 100;
Image histogram := RealImage("Histogram", 4, binCount);
Number binMin, binSize = (srcMax - srcMin) / binCount;
for (Number iBin = 0; iBin < binCount; iBin++)
{
    OpenAndSetProgressWindow("Ch: " + iBin, "", "");
    binMin = srcMin + iBin * binSize;
    histogram[0, iBin, 1, iBin + 1] = Sum(sourceImg >= binMin && sourceImg < binMin + binSize);
}
CloseProgressWindow();

// Integrate the histogram and locate the median channel
Number minX, minY;
histogram += histogram.Index(icol - 1, 0);
histogram -= srcW * srcH / 2;
histogram.Abs().Min(minX, minY);

// Compute the (approximate) median value
Number median = srcMin + (minX + 0.5) * binSize;
OKDialog("Median: " + median);

Maybe someone else knows a faster way to compute the histogram. That's the slowest part. Note that the precision of the returned median value is determined by the number of bins in the histogram and may be limited by the presence of outlier values or a very large dynamic range in the data. In the latter case, it might help to use a log scale for the histogram axis.

There is an function "ImageCalculateHistogram" that can generate histogram.  We can replace this section of codes
